# Updates page not showing formating

Tags: updates

When I go to the wp-admin/update-core.php page inside the admin with the admin user there is now css formatting. All other admin pages seam fine that I have checked. Does anyone know what could cause this?

Comment: Most likely, one of active plugins interferes with admin's interface. Try to deactivate all plugins and select 'Updates' again. You should get a clean interface. Activate plugins, one by one, going to 'Update' after each activation. That might identify the one causing problems.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I went through ant disabled all the plugins still not working. I even tried switching to 2016 for a theme and nothing. If I go to admin pages like post or page edit all looks good but if I go to updates, settings and several others I get an un formated admin page. Any idea of why this would be?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by Adding define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false ); to wp-config.php